# Ubuntu 18.04 strange sound volume behaviour on MSI GD63 7RD Stealth

Tags: 18.04, sound, headphones, volume-control

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my new Laptop (MSI GD63 7RD Stealth). The sound volume control is working perfectly until I plug my headphones in. If I do so the sound is also coming from the laptop speakers and with max volume from the headphones. The volume control then only works on the laptop speakers (headphones is always max volume) until its completely off. Then its also off on the headphones.

Does anyone know that behavior and how I can fix this?

**EDIT**:

`pacmd list-sinks | grep -e'name:' -e 'index:'`

```
  * index: 0
        name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pactl?
(I guess it's installed by default)
do this in terminal: pactl set-sink-volume 0 -50%

Comment: That only sets the volume for the laptop speakers, headphones remain 100%, except for 0

Comment: can you try this "pacmd list-sinks | grep -e'name:' -e 'index:' "  to see list of output source and capture the screen please